# Are there restrictions to using PayPal SDK on android?

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an android app. My app has in-app products for sell. My products are virtual goods and subscriptions. I have implemented Google's Inn-App Billing SDK. But now I am thinking of using the PayPal SDK instead. To clarify, let me elaborate on subscription: I don't mean "subscription" in the Google IAB sense of `inapp` versus `subs`. I use `inapp` to implement subscription. So really as far as the Google Api knows my users are buying `inapp`; it's only within the world of my app that I interpret these purchases as subscriptions.

With all that said, is any developer aware of legal restrictions imposed by google concerning using PayPal's SDK to implement subscriptions? The main concern is that I will be publishing my app through Google Play Store. And I don't know if they require that I use their Inn-App Billing for administering what is in fact subscription (although technically, I transact them as `inapp`).

For more details: a user has restricted use of my app. To get full use, they must subscribe to the "service" that my app is providing. The service is, for all practical purposes, virtual: through the app only. It's similar to unlocking levels in a game, except it is actually subscription: i.e. access for a set time, and you must buy again after the time is up.

Please, if you have had experience using PayPal in that sense, share your experience and perhaps some authoritative links explaining that my user case is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the developer docs, it doesn't sound like they'll let you process a payment directly from your app
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

> In general, the terms of Google Play allow you to sell in-app
>   subscriptions only through the standard payment processor, Google
>   Wallet. For purchases of any subscription products, the transaction
>   fee is the same as the transaction fee for application purchases
>   (30%).
>
> Apps published on Google Play that are selling subscriptions must use
>   In-app Billing to handle the transaction and may not provide links to
>   a purchase flow outside of the app and Google Play (such as to a web
>   site).

Comment: Thanks for a good response. +1. But my subscriptions are not `subs` I am using `inapp` and am only interpreting it as subscription. Does that technicality not matter.

Comment: Based on the above, I don't think you're allowed to collect any money outside of Google as part of your agreement to publish in Play Store. I know Apple has a similar requirement

Answer (score 0):

I believe one could redirect the user to an external website, collect the payment and then make the user "premium" / "subscriber" (on your server).

This way you are not collecting money from within the app.